# Can we use LiveData without loosing any value?

Tags: android, android-livedata

I would like to use a LiveData for handling kind of notifications, as it is already lifecycle aware, between a custom view and its wrapping fragment. But it seems that a LiveData may loose values : it will only update to its most recent state and also won't fire values during inactive state of its observers.

I've looked at the [SingleLiveEvent purpose](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/blob/dev-todo-mvvm-live/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/SingleLiveEvent.java) from Google code samples, but that solution does not seems to be battle tested yet, and the [ticket](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/issues/63) is still open with recent tries to improve the solution.

So I am looking for a simple way to get notified about events, and at the same time not being worried about Lifecycles (that was why I went for LiveData as a first solution), and that could handle multiple observers.

Is there an existing solution for that ? If I try to implement it, it is sure that I will land into at least an anti-pattern.

One easy way (perhaps too easy) is to use callbacks : but the problem is that I need this feature for several callbacks in my component, leading me in a poor architecture. And also, I want a subscribe system, meaning that there could be more than one observer.

One other way, could be to use RxJava and tranform it into a LiveData, with LiveDataReactiveStreams.fromPublisher() : but now the question is whether I will get all values or only the last one. That's the closest solution I could deal with.

As an interesting alternative there could be [AutoDispose](https://github.com/uber/AutoDispose) or [RxLifecycle](https://github.com/trello/RxLifecycle). And an interesting resource I've found : [Blog post on LiveData](https://blog.rocketinsights.com/rx-to-livedata/)

What are your thoughts, suggestions ?

Also, please notice that I need this communication from a component wrapped into a Fragment (ChessBoard) toward another Fragment (ChessHistory). So they are both lifecycle aware.

Answer (score 8):

It is not ideal, but this does the trick for me:

```
/**
* This LiveData will deliver values even when they are 
* posted very quickly one after another.
*/
class ValueKeeperLiveData<T> : MutableLiveData<T>() {

    private val queuedValues: Queue<T> = LinkedList<T>()

    @Synchronized
    override fun postValue(value: T) {
        // We queue the value to ensure it is delivered 
        // even if several ones are posted right after.
        // Then we call the base, which will eventually
        // call setValue().
        queuedValues.offer(value)
        super.postValue(value)
    }

    @MainThread
    @Synchronized
    override fun setValue(value: T) {
        // We first try to remove the value from the queue just
        // in case this line was reached from postValue(),
        // otherwise we will have it duplicated in the queue.
        queuedValues.remove(value)

        // We queue the new value and finally deliver the
        // entire queue of values to the observers.
        queuedValues.offer(value)
        while (!queuedValues.isEmpty())
            super.setValue(queuedValues.poll())
    }
}
```

The main problem with this solution is that if the observers are inactive at the time the values are delivered via `super.setValue()`, then the values will be lost regardless. However, it solves the issue of losing values when several new ones are posted very quickly – which, in my opinion, is usually a bigger problem than losing values because your observer is inactive. After all, you can always do `myLiveData.observeForever()` from a non-lifecycle-aware object in order to receive all notifications.

Not sure this will be enough for you, but I hope it can help you or give you some ideas about how to implement your own approach.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. As I am progressing in my researchs, I am getting more and more conviced that LiveData is not adapted to my need. But I'd rather use something like AutoDispose or RxLifeCycle I pointed to in my question. Only one thing that I must get used to (more than before): Rx -> RxJava/RxKotlin. Indeed I do want to keep and transfer all values from Observables. This is specially important for a domain like chess moves for example.

Comment: I don't know your use case, but if you need to deliver values to a custom view without losing any, this should probably be enough. Your view won't get certain values if its fragment happens to be inactive at the time they are delivered, but that should be fine because an inactive fragment means that the view is not even displayed.

Comment: If you want to update the state of a chess board game via individual movements delivered somehow one after another, then `LiveData` isn't a good option – unless you deliver the entire board state every time. For example, you can use a `LiveData` to notify about the changes on a list, but to do so you must deliver the entire list as a value every single time, not just the new/updated/deleted items.

Comment: If I want to process chess moves from a Chess Fragment (Board) to another related Chess Fragment (History), then I can't afford loose any value. And you're right, for this kind of process, LiveData is not adapted. That's why I am (re-)learning RxJava along with AutoDisposible/RxLifecycle.

Comment: Well, to be fair, you could this version of `LiveData` for that purpose, as long as your observer is not a lifecycle instance, but an object that will never stop receiving notifications (you can do `myLiveData.observeForever()` from any object in your app).

Comment: "as long as your observer is not a lifecycle instance", and that condition won't be achieved, as it is a communication between two visibles fragments: From ChessBoard (move validation) to ChessHistory (move register).

Comment: You could turn the `ChessHistory` into a model and then make the view reflect its state. If you perform your subscription to the `ValueKeeperLiveData` via `observeForever()` from this model instead of from the view, you won't lose any values.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193212/discussion-between-loloof64-and-julio-e-rodriguez-cabanas).